# Algorithm complexity, log^k n vs n log n

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

I am developing some algorithm with takes up O(log^3 n). (NOTE: Take O as Big Theta, though Big O would be fine too)

I am unsure whereas O(log^3 n), or even O(log^2 n), is considered to be more/less/equaly complex as O(n log n).

If I were to follow the rules stright away, I'd say O(n log n) is the more complex one, but still, I don't have any clue as why or how.

I've done some research but I haven't been able to find an answer to this question.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which is bigger, log^3(100000) or 1000000*log(1000000)?

Comment: nlogn is more complex neither log^2n, for example if we have N equals to 1024, we have 1024*10 > 10*10 (log base is 2)

Comment: @JohnKugelman you should post this as the answer.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Absolutely right. Please post that as an answer. Would O(n log n) be accepted as a Greedy algorithm?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Thus (n log n) is "bigger" than ((log n)<sup>3</sup>). This could be easily generalized to ((log n)<sup>k</sup>) via induction.

Answer (score 9):

If you [graph the two functions together](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%5E3%28n%29+vs+n+log%28n%29+from+0+to+100) you can see that *n* log(*n*) grows faster than log<sup>3</sup> *n*.

[image]

To prove this, you need to prove that *n* log *n* > log<sup>3</sup> *n* for all values of *n* greater than some arbitrary number *c*. Find such a *c* and you have your proof.

In fact, [*n* log(*n*) grows faster than any log<sup>*x*</sup> *n*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%5E10%28n%29+vs+n+log%28n%29+from+0+to+10%5E14) for positive *x*.

[image]